# Как убрать лишнее и оставить только массив из чисел

Tags: python

Вот мой код

`data = 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]`

```
import numpy as np

def data_reverse(data):
    a = np.array_split(data, len(data) / 8)
    return a[::-1]
```

Он возвращает `[array([1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]), array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]), array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]), array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])]`

Как убрать лишние скобки и "array", что бы получить на выходе `[1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[j for i in a[::-1] for j in i]
```

Answer (score 0):

[numpy.concatenate](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html):

```
import numpy as np


def data_reverse(data):
    return np.concatenate(np.array_split(data, len(data) / 8)[::-1])


print(data_reverse([
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1,
    1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0
]))
```

> ```
> [1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
> ```